# How to add action to controller in api mvc project net core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I'm trying to make an IdentityServer4 starting from a Microsoft example.

The example contains an Api project and an mcv client to authenticate and call the api.

[image]

Api project Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                options.Audience = "api1";
            });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Api IdentityController.cs:

```
namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("identity")]
    [Authorize]
    public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
        }
    }
}
```

this code in MvcClient invoke correctly the action of IdentityController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CallApi()
{
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity");

        ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
        return View("json");
}
```

I added one action named Test to IdentityController:

```
namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("identity")]
    [Authorize]
    public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
        }

        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
        }
    }
}
```

But this code throw 404 not found in McvClient:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CallTestApi()
{
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:5001/identity/Test");

        ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(content).ToString();
        return View("json");
}
```

[image]

Comment: 404, I think your server is not started or endpoint does not exist

Comment: the server is starded, http://localhost:5001/identity works fine. but how to call another action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample uses [HTTP verb route template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#http-verb-templates). As you see `[Route("identity")]` is on controller level, and `Get` falls under default get for the controller. But for `Test` action you need to add `[HttpGet("test")]`. Read more about routing [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1). The code would be like this:

```
namespace Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("identity")]
    [Authorize]
    public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
        }

        [HttpGet("test")]
        public IActionResult Test()
        {
            return new JsonResult(from c in User.Claims select new { c.Type, c.Value });
        }
    }
}
```